# Cron jobs in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I am trying to do a cron job with a site built in CodeIgniter - I've got access to the CPanel cron feature can anyone suggest the best way to setup a cron job using CPanel?

I am using CodIgniter so cannot be sure how to call a controller within a cron job?

E.g `http://admin.com/sites/publish/`

How would I access this publish function within the sites controllers using a cron job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best way is to call from the command line in the cron job...

```
php /path/to/index.php controller >> /dev/null
```

You can run controllers via the command line in CI, see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).

Comment: Would this be correct for my purpose do you think?

php /home/username/public_html/index.php/sites/publish >> /dev/null

Comment: +1 from me but I'll just add based on the question and the path given you'd use `php /path/to/index.php sites publish >> /dev/null` (realise you've just given an example just thought I'd clarify)

Comment: Hi again - just tried and the cron is running but I get the following Cron Daemon message sent to me.

NB The controller is called sites & the function is called cron

/bin/sh: /home/username/public_html/index.php/sites/publish: Not a directory

Comment: Does the command line stuff work in the legacy stuff? The site I have is very old using around version 1.6 of Codeigniter I believe :(

Comment: No your command is wrong it should be `/home/username/public_html/index.php sites publish` after the index.php you send the controller as the parameters.

Comment: @fire kinda gets there but I now get this - i may try to try a non codeigniter file (with sum good ol' mysql)

/home/username/public_html/index.php: line 1: ?php
: No such file or directory
/home/username/public_html/index.php: line 2: /*
: No such file or directory
/home/username/public_html/index.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
/home/username/public_html/index.php: line 3: `|---------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I didn't see the path to PHP in your command, also you can try putting the parameters in quotes e.g..... `php /home/username/public_html/index.php "sites publish"`

Comment: ok - so i presume this would be right :-
/usr/bin php /home/username/public_html/index.php "sites publish"

Comment: Only you can tell me that! If it works then the answer is yes ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3240/discussion-between-fire-and-gaz)

Comment: just updating the URL provided in this already wonderful answer :P http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Answer (score 5):

For me the easier way of doing this is using cURL and executing the url in the cron:

```
curl http://admin.com/sites/publish/
```

If you need to secure the url, you could send data via post using:

```
curl -X POST -d "apikey=yourapikey&another=variable" http://admin.com/sites/publish/
```

This way you don't have to fight with php parameters and different configurations.

Comment: using this, you expose your cron jobs to the whole world

Comment: You could protect them using a htpasswd. I know it's safer using php instead of curl, but for some silly stuff it's easier this way.

Answer (score 2):

I do this such way, 
create folder cron

```
/application
/cron
   my_task.php
/public
```

make script for each cron job /cron/my_task.php with content

```
<?  $_SERVER["SCRIPT_URL"] = "/controllerName/MethodName"; // you can set url in routes if you want
    $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] = "your_site_address.com"; // without http://www
    require(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../public/index.php");  // path to index.php
 ?>
```

make controller Cron like others, but add validation on IP in __construct

and finaly run like

```
1 10 * * * cd /path_to_site_folder/cron/ && usr/local/bin/php /path_to_site_folder/cron/my_task.php >> path_to_log/some.log
```

Answer (score 1):

For Cronjob try this to access command line controller, functions and params:

```
php index.php/controller/function/param1/param2/param3 etc
```

or

```
php index.php controller function param1 param2 param3 etc
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this command and paste it.

```
wget www.example.com/index.php/controller/function
```