# CodeIgniter CRON job

Tags: codeigniter, cron

I'm trying to set up a **CRON** job to make some database changes on a **CodeIgniter** install and having issues with the host that are stopping it from working. The host's CRON setup only allows you to execute a PHP file rather than calling a URL.

What I've tried:

`Curl, wget, file_get_contents, fopen, http_get` from a static PHP file - all not allowed by the host

`/path/to/php /path/to/index.php` controller method - to use the command line interface

After unfruitful conversations with the host I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know how I could call a controller method from a static PHP file without the above?

Comment: I use the CLI method and it works... what version of PHP? do you know your host's flavor of Linux?

Comment: Are you working on a shared host or a virtual dedicated server (VPS)?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what exact flavour of Linux it is, or how to find out, but I can see this under phpinfo: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu . The commands can be run through PHP 4 or PHP 5.2 and it's on a shared host

Comment: Your best bet might be to post something on the community forum or bulletin board of our hosting company (if possible).  This issue is very server dependent.  Sorry I can't be of much help.

Comment: try this solutions 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322378/cron-jobs-in-codeigniter

Comment: Thanks for the tips / link but still no joy - the host seems to have locked down anything but direct file execution - still open to ideas

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you are using CI ver 2> (CLI support was not available before).

Secondly, lets say that the page you are trying to fire under cron is http://www.mysite.com/index.php/cronjobs/thejob

The correct command would be:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/rootCIfolder/index.php cronjobs thejob
```

Replace `/usr/bin/php` with the location of your php executable and `/var/www/rootCIfolder` with the location of your CI folder.

You need to have php compiled with command line support. You can verify this by:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2012 16:53:21)
```

Comment: What about the cronjobs & thejob? Controller and method?

Comment: @Udhay yes, "cronjobs" is the controller and "thejob" is the method.