# how to send an automatic email after a specific interval in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a codeigniter project where an automatic aunction system has been integrated.The seller posts his domain name for auction and specifies an end date for the auction for that domain.
My question is that how to send an automatic email to seller when the specific period of auction for his domain expires or his domain is sold to the highest bidder after the auction period ends.     http://superhitdomains.com/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to read about [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), set up job for every day/hour, create script (CI script) that is going to check your table with "end dates" if there is one/more send email/s otherwise tell server to chillax. Also cron+CI is a bit complicated you'll need to research that as well, for example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7326886/1564365

Comment: make a controller function and add to it in cron job

Comment: is there not another way like ajax ?

Comment: if the site is high traffic you can set up this script to load on every page load (note that this is the worst solution ever), [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is out of question mate.

Answer (score 1):

Use Routes for configuration of your url and make a seperate controller for the email trigger and then set this function into cron job part in your cpanel hope this works